# D3.symbol in the corner of the screen. I would like to move it

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
d3.select("#svgpathSVGdata").select("svg").append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up"))
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .style("fill", "black");
```

This is the svg.symbol that is in the top left of my page. I wish to at least of have it in the middle, is it possible to move it with x or y? http://jsfiddle.net/xwZjN/21/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to how you select the svg element to append your path element to.

At the start of your code you create a new `svg` element and you add an `g` element to it, which you transform into the desired location:

```
  var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg") 
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r +") rotate(180) scale(-1, -1)");
```

It's important to realize that the variable `svg` corresponds to the inner `g` element. Its origin is in the center of your arcs (it's translated (500,500) from the top left corner). This is the element you want to append new elements to. In fact, in most of your code you do use that variable. For example:

```
   var node = svg.selectAll("circle.node")
       .data(nodes)
     .enter().append("path")
       .attr("class", "node")
```

Now, when you add your black triangle you used the following:

```
d3.select("#chart").select("svg").append("path")
```

However, this will select the outer `svg` element, while we wanted to select the inner `g` element. Of course you could fix it by saying:

```
d3.select("#chart").select("svg").select("g").append("path")
```

, but the cleaner approach is to keep using the svg variable:

```
svg.append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up"))
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .style("fill", "black");
```

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xwZjN/24/

Comment: Hi nautat, Could you explain how you would attach text/labels to that svg.symbol?

Comment: See editted answer above. I didn't read your code carefully enough to see your problem was related to the svg selection.

Comment: To add text you can group your path and text in a g element: 

var g = svg.append("g");
       
   g.append("path")
        .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up"))
        .attr("transform", "translate(-10,-5)")
        .style("fill", "black");

   g.append("text")
       .text("symbol text");

Comment: but, when I move the translate by changing the transform, the text doesn't move in the same direction.. any help?

Comment: The symbol path and text elements are wrapped in a g element. Of course you have to translate this parent g element if you want to move both the text and symbol: http://jsfiddle.net/xwZjN/28/

Comment: ah, all this time I tried to return the transform of triangle - thanks again!